# Exporting a computer list with OS version and up/down pings

Tags: csv, scripting, operating-system, export, powershell-ise

I'm writing a script in PowerShell-ISE that allows me to ping a computer list and exports the pings associated with each computer as well as the OS version into a CSV. Below is what I got so far. I'm not exactly sure where to put the `Test-Connection` in here.

```bsh
$good = "C:\Users\1521599002A\Desktop\good.csv"
$bad = "C:\Users\1521599002A\Desktop\bad.csv"

$Computers = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\1521599002A\Desktop\complist.txt" -Header "Name"

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    try {
        Get-ADComputer -Identity $Computer.Name -Properties Name, operatingSystem |
            Select Name, operatingSystem
        Out-File -FilePath $good -InputObject "$Computer" -Append -Force
    } catch {
        $Computer.Name + " not in AD"
        Out-File -FilePath $bad -InputObject "$Computer" -Append -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: @GiulioBambini Would you kindly refrain from editing PowerShell code when you don't know PowerShell? Thank you.

Comment: Forgive me @AnsgarWiechers I've just tried to help, the question was really   bad formatted as code indentation. And you're right, I don't know so much about PowerShell. Next time I'll probably just `flag` it for request a moderation by an expert.

Comment: @GiulioBambini Poor formatting doesn't warrant a moderator flag. The community usually takes care of that. Your edit would've been OK had you simply indented the code. But please don't make changes to the syntax when you don't know what the code does.